# Android. How to move object in the direction it is facing (using Vector3 and Quaternion)

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I'm using libGDX (quite new to it in fact) and Android. And I want to move 3d object in the direction it is facing (using some speed). I thinks it's a basic question but can't find a straight nswer for it. I have a Quaternion representing object rotation(direction) and I have a Vector3 representing the object position. The question is how to update the position Vector3 using info from Quaternion in order to move object in the direction represented by Quaternion. (An alternative to this is extract roll pitch and yaw from Quaternion and get the new coords by applying trigonometric calculations. But i think there must be a way to achieve this using Vector3 and Quat.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quaternion is used to specify a rotation. You first need to specify the direction when no rotation is applied. For example if you want to move along the X axis when no rotation is applied:

```
Vector3 baseDirection = new Vector3(1,0,0);
```

Make sure the base direction is normalized (length = 1),you can use the `nor()` method to be safe:

```
Vector3 baseDirection = new Vector3(1,0,0).nor();
```

Next you'll need to rotate the direction using the Quaternion:

```
Vector3 direction = new Vector3();
Quaternion rotation = your_quaternion;
direction.set(baseDirection);
direction.mul(rotation);
```

Now that you have the direction, you can scale it with the amount you want to move it. You'll probably want to do this every frame and depending on the time elapsed since the last frame.

```
final float speed = 5f; // 5 units per second
Vector3 translation = new Vector3();
translation.set(direction);
translation.scl(speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
```

Finally you need to add the translation to the position

```
position.add(translation);
```

Of course, depending on your actual implementation you can batch multiple operations, e.g.:

```
translation.set(baseDirection).mul(rotation).scl(speed * Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
position.add(translation);
```

**Update:**
Adding working code from Xoppa's comment:

```
translation.set(baseDirection).rot(modelInstance.transform).nor().scl(speed * delta)
```

Comment: Hi Xoppa! Thanks for you answer. It looks like the thing I've been looking for. But unfortunately it doesn't work as expected. I used your code as is and I get strange results. My object starts facing right(X axis). then I rotate it by say 35 degrees around Z axis. The object is looking a bit upwards. I apply your code and expect the object to move  to the right and up. But it is moved to the right with very small displacement to the top. 35 degree should give dY/dX=0.7 (tan(35)). Can you please help?

Comment: Hello again Xoppa. After some investigation i got a feeling that there's something wrong with Quaternion i get. I created the same scene in Rajawali(3d engine). rotate object by the same 35 degrees. and used their quaternion with your code. It works like a charm. dY/dX = 0.7. Flawless. So the answer is correct. But the quaternion I get from libgdx is wrong(wrong values compared to the one that worked(from Rajawali)). I get it using: modelInstance.transform.getRotation(quaternion). Is this the correct way?

Comment: Is you model instance scaled? iirc you can rotate a Vector3 directly using a Matrix4, so you skip the quaternion `direction.set(baseDirection).rotate(modelInstance.transform).nor()`. Or if you're using the latter method: `translation.set(baseDirection).rotate(modelInstance.transform).nor().scl(speed * delta)`. Note that I'm not sure about the `rotate()` method, it might be called `rot()` (but not `mul()`).

Comment: Hi Xoppa! Thanks! It works like a charm!:) By the way thanks for your tutorials. Really helped me to start with lidgdx