# how to move a 3d model according to its direction

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, libgdx

I am a newbie to libgdx and android programming in general......so am trying to make a game with libgdx where the user uses accelerometer to move a model....but i can't seem to figure out how to properly move the model where its facing....i used both codes from a similar queation at this link......[Android. How to move object in the direction it is facing (using Vector3 and Quaternion)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18485854/android-how-to-move-object-in-the-direction-it-is-facing-using-vector3-and-qua)..... but it doesnt work properly....i guess it has something to do with an update cos that answer is old......thanks for any help

This is the code i tried

```
public Vector3 baseDirection;
public Vector3 position;
public Quaternion rotation;
public Vector3 translation;
...
public void show
{
baseDirection=new Vector3(0,0,1).nor();
.....
}
public void render
{
direction.mul(rotation);
translation.set(direction);
translation.scl(speed*delta);
instance.transform.translate(translation.x/100f,tranlation.y/100f,translation.z/100f);
}
```

Then i tried this

```
public void render
{
direction.rot(instance.transform).nor().scl(speed*delta);
position.add(direction);
}
```

Whit the first code it moves in its direction but when i turn it around to the initial point its as if all the code goes upside down
......then with the second code it moves forward perfectly but if i turn it sideways slightly it move sideways fully

Comment: You need to share the code you tried and explain what "doesn't work properly" means for us to be able to help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I saw my problem......the second code worked better....i didnt need to add traslation vector to position vector all i needed to do was translate instance by translation vector

```
translation.set(direction).rot(instance.transform).nor().scl(speed*delta);
instance.transform.translate(translation);
```

It worked perfectly