# I want to apply force in the facing direction of a sprite

Tags: android, box2d, andengine, 2d-games, google-play-games

I am developing a game in andengine and I want to apply a Force to my Sprite. The thing is I rotate the sprite with a controller and I want a force to be applied on the direction the sprite is facing (Sprite is a rocket).

Thanks in advance hope I explained it well.

Comment: Create PhysicsHandler object and then apply velocity and then connect the sprite to this handler.It will work.

Comment: can you provide me with some code or something I don't quite understand you I tried something but it doesn't work

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164146/simple-gun-in-cocos2dbox2d-game

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the facing direction using this

```
currentVelocity = new Vector2((float)Math.cos(body.getAngle()) * magnitude, (float) Math.sin(body.getAngle()) * magnitude);
    body.applyForce(currentVelocity, body.getPosition());
```

magnitude is a float variable.

Comment: depending on the looks of the sprite you maybe need to play with the sin and cos maybe change them (cos to sin and sin to cos) and maybe add negative values to x or y od the vector2. That's just a tip for viewers on this post I had problems and I solved it that way :)

Answer (score 0):

```
  Sprite  pSprite = new Sprite(23, 43, pTextureRegion, pVertexBufferObject);
    PhysicsHandler handler = new PhysicsHandler(pSprite);
    handler.setVelocityX(pVelocityX);
   handler.setVelocityY(pVelocityY);
```

In this way you can implement.
If it is not adjusting then you can creating  body  for that particular  sprite and apply force to that body

Comment: Thanks I found another way to deal with this but I'll maybe try that too :]